# How to download and extract http file from POST Query using powershell?

Tags: powershell, rest, csv

I am trying to create an automation script with REST API to pull a report from our phone provider as mentioned here https://developer.flowroute.com/api/cdrexports/v2.0/query-cdrs/ using PowerShell. I am new to API's and still getting my footing with PowerShell as well so any tips are appreciated! So far I am able to POST a query to Flowroute which works but where I am having issues is downloading the file so I can extract and pull the report they mention here https://developer.flowroute.com/api/cdrexports/v2.0/cdr-results/. I am confused how I am able to download this within the same script if the response is all that comes back. I have thought of using Get-Member to create a variable from the NoteProperty and then try to query again to get the download link they mention but have not had much luck.

I have tried manually downloading the report that POSTS but do not see how I can get the unique download link Flowroute mentions to pull the response data and extract the gz archive file it creates from my POST query all in the same script. Below is my POST code and the response I receive.

POST QUERY:

```
$headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/vnd.api+json")
$headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic code=password")

$body = @"
{
  `"data`": {
    `"type`": `"cdrexport`",
    
    
    `"attributes`": {

      `"filter_parameters`": {
        `"start_call_start_time`": `"2023-07-01 00:00:00`",
        `"start_call_end_time`": `"2023-07-31 00:00:00`",
        `"destination_numbers`": ["phone number"]
      }
    }
  }
}
"@

$response = Invoke-RestMethod 'https://api.url.com' -Method 'POST' -Headers $headers -Body $body
$response | ConvertTo-Json


$response | Get-member
```

End of Query

Response given back from $response | Get-member Query

TypeName: System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject

```
Name        MemberType   Definition                                                                                        
----        ----------   ----------                                                                                        
Equals      Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)                                                                    
GetHashCode Method       int GetHashCode()                                                                                 
GetType     Method       type GetType()                                                                                    
ToString    Method       string ToString()                                                                                 
data        NoteProperty System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject data=@{attributes=; id=586377; links=; type=cdrexport}
```

End of Response code

Apologies if this is extensive but I feel like I am stuck and would love to automate this. Any best practices or advice on where to go from here is appreciated!

Comment: Apart from your actual problem, one thing you can do to make it easier to generate json text is build a hashtable and then use ```ConvertTo-Json``` - e.g. ```$body = @{ "data" = @{ "type" = "cdrexport" ... etc ... } } | ConvertTo-Json``` - it'll look very similar to what you've already got, and the advantage is PowerShell will validate the hashtable syntax for you, rather than wait for the REST api to reject badly formatted hand-crafted json text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question and the documentation, it seems that the data returned in the `Invoke-RestMethod` is just an ID as mentioned in the "[CDR Export data](https://developer.flowroute.com/api/cdrexports/v2.0/cdr-results/)" page.

You can :

- Gather this ID from your `$response`
- query the status of your export request using this ID
- Download the report with the URL provided from the status query from the `download_url` attribute

Also as mentioned by mclayton, you could rewrite in an easier way your body and header to make it more flexible and reusable with hashtables

```
    $BaseUrl = "https://" + "api.flowroute.com"
    $Headers = @{
        "Content-Type" = "application/vnd.api+json"
        Authorization  = "Basic code=password"
    }

    $body = @{
        data = @{
            type = "cdrexport"
            attributes = @{
                filter_parameters = @{
                    start_call_start_time = "2023-07-01 00:00:00"
                    start_call_end_time = "2023-07-31 00:00:00"
                    destination_numbers = @("phone number")
                }
            }
        }
    }

    $response = Invoke-RestMethod $BaseUrl -Method "POST" -Headers $headers -Body $body
```

From the documentation again, you can call the [status of your request](https://developer.flowroute.com/api/cdrexports/v2.0/cdr-status/) using your the request ID stored in your $response data property. the `download_url` is available in this status request, and if the structure is correct, it should look like something lke that :

Note : I'd put the script to sleep for a few seconds for the 2nd part to give the time to your API to answer or finish generating your report

```
    # Sleep
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 5

    # New URL to query
    # Based on documentation, endpoint to query is "/cdrs/exports/:cdrexport_id"
    # Gathering ID from previous query
    $URI = $BaseUrl + "/v2/cdrs/exports/" + $response.data.id

    # Status of your query via a GET request, no body needed
    $status = Invoke-RestMethod $URI -Method "GET" -Headers $headers

    # download URL
    $download_url = $status.data.attributes.download_url

    # Download the report
    $output = "C:\Temp"
    Invoke-WebRequest -uri $download_url -outfile $output

    $FilePath = "C:\Temp\myfile.gz"
    # Extract the contents of the file using Expand-Archive
    Expand-Archive -Path $FilePath -DestinationPath "C:\Temp"
```

Hope it helps. Let me know if it works

Comment: Hi Douda, thanks so much for the info. I tried using hashtables as you mentioned but it did not like the formatting but did change the headers which was cleaner. I was able to download using your last method but brings up a different problem. The file is encrypted and when I directly download the file it created It comes out as a gz file which 7zip can open. I also could not use just C:temp as the output as I got an access denied error so I placed a file name so it could download. I have tried a few options like renaming to gz instead of csv but it did not work. Any ideas?

Comment: To clarify on the encrypted file, 7zip can not open the file it downloads.

Comment: the C:\Temp was just an example. Modify it where you have rights to write your files.
Regarding your .gz extension, it seems it's just a standard archive that you can extract. I updated the code to my answer

Comment: I figured it out using 7zip command line. Just had to adjust a few things and it worked! Thank you for your help!